# equal to operator is called without if condition

Tags: c

I was looking into some old code in my product and i found following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *str = "abcdefghi";
    int value = strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0;
}
```

What is the purpose of `int value = strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0;` of such code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It initializes `value` with the result of `strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0` which will be `0` or `1` depending on what `strcmp` returns.

Answer (score 1):

The result of using relational operators in a C expression result in either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

If `strcmp(str, "abcdefghi")` returns `0` then `strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0` will return true and `value` would be assigned a value 1. If it returns 1 then `value` would be assigned a value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0;
```

is something like

```
int value = (strcmp(str, "abcdefghi") == 0);
```

now inside () if strcmp returns 0 then (0 == 0) which means it will give 1

```
          if strcmp returns anything else then 0 then () will give 0
```